# Hibernate throwing ConcurrentModificationException with an embedded ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm running Hibernate 4.2.6.Final / JPA2 and trying to have an @ElementCollection List of @Embeddable objects which themselves contain an @ElementCollection List of String.

However, hibernate is throwing a ConcurrentModificationException when trying to instantiate the EntityManager, which I do not understand at all.

If I comment out my `List<Address>` in `User`, everything runs properly.  Similarly, if I comment out the `List<String> street` in `Address`, everything launches properly as well.  I am presuming it has something to do with an ElementCollection having its own embedded ElementCollection.

```
public class User {

    @TableGenerator( name="UUIDGenerator", pkColumnValue="user_id", table="uuid_generator", allocationSize=1)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     * Login username
     */
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    /**
     * Password in encrypted format
     */
    private String password;
    /**
     * Address
     */
    @Valid
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name="user_address", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Address> address;

   // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}


@Embeddable
public class Address {

    /**
     * Multiple street lines allowable
     */
    @NotBlank
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable( joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> street;

    /**
     * City
     */
    private String city;

    /**
     * State/Province
     */
    private String state;

    /**
     * Country
     */
    private String country;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}


Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1633)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1390)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1777)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 40 more
```

Am I not allowed having an embedded class have its own `@ElementCollection`? Is this not allowed?  How do I do this otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent some time digging around a little more and found this [similar issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589409/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-on-collectionofelements) which in turn references this Jira issue:

[ConcurrentModificationException when collection of embeddable contains a collection](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4313)

It was already raised in 2007, but to date nothing has been implemented for it.

Workaround at the moment is to make Address into an `Entity`, but maintain the lifecycle through `User`.

Answer (score 2):

This an issue that was already reported to Hibernate developers and no fix is scheduled! Sorry. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4313.